# Iterable printing name of the java object and not the value of the object

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-boot, jaxb

I have an API, In my model objects one of the property has **Iterable** as return type-

basically I am converting v6 objects to v8 objects.

```
    @XmlElement(name = "showTimeDetails")
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Some text")
    Iterable<ShowAvailabilityDetail> getShowAvailabilityDetails();
```

and when I am setting the value of `setShowAvailabilityDetails(List<Object>);` -

```
List<ShowAvailabilityDetail> fadV6 = showAccountTransactionV6
                    .getShowAvailabilityDetails();

showAccountTransactionV8.setShowAvailabilityDetails(fadV6)
```

as a List type and print this value in json, it prints the internal object name -

```
"showTimeDetails":someobjectname.java.com.somethinng.321312343242498
```

since all collections implement Iterable, I am not sure why it would not print the values.

and when I changed the property return type to List it has print the real values-

```
 @XmlElement(name = "showTimeDetails")
 @ApiModelProperty(value = "Some text")
 List<ShowAvailabilityDetail> getShowAvailabilityDetails();
```

Please help me understand why it would not behave the same with return type Iterable as List implements Iterable.